# Maven dependancies not installing Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1 Mac

Tags: maven, cucumber

I'm new to Java and cucumber framework. I'm in the process of creating my own cucumber framework using Maven but when I'm putting my dependancies in my POM.XML it's unable to find it. The error says dependancy not found.

I've tried to download Maven sources and get the error below. Not sure if the two are related but I assume so?. I'm a Mac user any help would be appreciated

Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is:

I've tried a few things below but had no luck

- Checking sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file
- apachectl configtest

  4.0.0

  ```
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>CucumberTemplate</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
  ```

Comment: First: `Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is:` does that happen during build time or runtime?

Comment: I've seen the error then I try to download Maven sources I assume the dependancies not being recognised is the same issue?

Comment: Please show your settings.xml file and furthermore can you explain why you are editing a apache httpd conf file?

Comment: Thank you so much. That's resolved the issue for me. I create the settings.xml file and it automatically began downloading the dependancies.

Comment: That sounds strange because you have to configured something very strange ... because usually everything is downloaded from central repository https://repo1.maven.org/... without supplemental configuration... can you show/write what you have changed/added in the settings.xml...

Comment: I didn't add anything. I right clicked pom.xml ->Maven -> there was an option to create the settings.xml which I done and it began working. Very weird

Comment: Where have you clicked? Take a look into $HOME/.m2/ ?